# Data organization for paired t-test function in R using formula representation

Tags: r

I try to understand how the paired `t.test()` function in R calculates the differences between subjects using the formula specification (`y ~ x`), that is when the data is ordered in the long format and **(a)** arranged by row number or **(b)** arranged by treatment level (see examples below).

For the paired t-test, differences between the **same** subjects have to be calculated first (followed by other calculations). So if I change the order, how does R figure out which subjects belong together? I looked up the source code for the `t.test()` function (see below) but from there I cannot figure this out. My intuition tells me that it must be something like "*take the first occurrence of level 1 and subtract this from the first occurrence of level 2, then the second, third, etc.*". And this seems to be confirmed by the examples below. When I shuffle the rows randomly, only then is the result slightly different for the `t` and `p-value`.

**Question**: Which functions in the source code in the `t.test()` function (see below) make the calculation of the differences between subjects correct, despite the order of the rows being different?

```r
require(tidyverse)
#> Loading required package: tidyverse
set.seed(1)
## create some toy data to run paired t.test
d <-
  tibble(ID = 1:10 ,
         PRE = c(rnorm(10, mean = 4, sd = 2)),
         POST = c(rnorm(10, mean = 6, sd = 2)))

d
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>       ID   PRE  POST
#>    <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     1  2.75  9.02
#>  2     2  4.37  6.78
#>  3     3  2.33  4.76
#>  4     4  7.19  1.57
#>  5     5  4.66  8.25
#>  6     6  2.36  5.91
#>  7     7  4.97  5.97
#>  8     8  5.48  7.89
#>  9     9  5.15  7.64
#> 10    10  3.39  7.19

## pivot long to use the formula representation in t.test
d_long <- d %>%
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "treat", values_to = "values")
d_long
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#>       ID treat values
#>    <int> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1     1 PRE     2.75
#>  2     1 POST    9.02
#>  3     2 PRE     4.37
#>  4     2 POST    6.78
#>  5     3 PRE     2.33
#>  6     3 POST    4.76
#>  7     4 PRE     7.19
#>  8     4 POST    1.57
#>  9     5 PRE     4.66
#> 10     5 POST    8.25
#> 11     6 PRE     2.36
#> 12     6 POST    5.91
#> 13     7 PRE     4.97
#> 14     7 POST    5.97
#> 15     8 PRE     5.48
#> 16     8 POST    7.89
#> 17     9 PRE     5.15
#> 18     9 POST    7.64
#> 19    10 PRE     3.39
#> 20    10 POST    7.19

## arrange by treat variable to change order
d_long_arranged <- d_long %>% 
  arrange(desc(treat))
d_long_arranged
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#>       ID treat values
#>    <int> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1     1 PRE     2.75
#>  2     2 PRE     4.37
#>  3     3 PRE     2.33
#>  4     4 PRE     7.19
#>  5     5 PRE     4.66
#>  6     6 PRE     2.36
#>  7     7 PRE     4.97
#>  8     8 PRE     5.48
#>  9     9 PRE     5.15
#> 10    10 PRE     3.39
#> 11     1 POST    9.02
#> 12     2 POST    6.78
#> 13     3 POST    4.76
#> 14     4 POST    1.57
#> 15     5 POST    8.25
#> 16     6 POST    5.91
#> 17     7 POST    5.97
#> 18     8 POST    7.89
#> 19     9 POST    7.64
#> 20    10 POST    7.19

## randomly rearrange order of rows
d_long_random <- d_long %>% 
  slice(sample(1:n()))
d_long_random
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#>       ID treat values
#>    <int> <chr>  <dbl>
#>  1     5 POST    8.25
#>  2     3 POST    4.76
#>  3     8 PRE     5.48
#>  4     6 POST    5.91
#>  5     5 PRE     4.66
#>  6     4 PRE     7.19
#>  7    10 PRE     3.39
#>  8     8 POST    7.89
#>  9     4 POST    1.57
#> 10     7 PRE     4.97
#> 11     9 POST    7.64
#> 12     9 PRE     5.15
#> 13     7 POST    5.97
#> 14     1 POST    9.02
#> 15     2 PRE     4.37
#> 16    10 POST    7.19
#> 17     3 PRE     2.33
#> 18     2 POST    6.78
#> 19     6 PRE     2.36
#> 20     1 PRE     2.75

## Run t.tests
t.test(d$POST, d$PRE, paired = T)
#> 
#>  Paired t-test
#> 
#> data:  d$POST and d$PRE
#> t = 2.2879, df = 9, p-value = 0.04794
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.02508677 4.44148199
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of the differences 
#>                2.233284
t.test(values ~ treat, paired = T, d_long)
#> 
#>  Paired t-test
#> 
#> data:  values by treat
#> t = 2.2879, df = 9, p-value = 0.04794
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.02508677 4.44148199
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of the differences 
#>                2.233284
t.test(values ~ treat, paired = T, d_long_arranged)
#> 
#>  Paired t-test
#> 
#> data:  values by treat
#> t = 2.2879, df = 9, p-value = 0.04794
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.02508677 4.44148199
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of the differences 
#>                2.233284
t.test(values ~ treat, paired = T, d_long_random)
#> 
#>  Paired t-test
#> 
#> data:  values by treat
#> t = 2.3054, df = 9, p-value = 0.04658
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  0.04193459 4.42463416
#> sample estimates:
#> mean of the differences 
#>                2.233284

## pull up t.test.default source code
getAnywhere(t.test.default)
#> A single object matching 't.test.default' was found
#> It was found in the following places
#>   registered S3 method for t.test from namespace stats
#>   namespace:stats
#> with value
#> 
#> function (x, y = NULL, alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"), 
#>     mu = 0, paired = FALSE, var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, 
#>     ...) 
#> {
#>     alternative <- match.arg(alternative)
#>     if (!missing(mu) && (length(mu) != 1 || is.na(mu))) 
#>         stop("'mu' must be a single number")
#>     if (!missing(conf.level) && (length(conf.level) != 1 || !is.finite(conf.level) || 
#>         conf.level < 0 || conf.level > 1)) 
#>         stop("'conf.level' must be a single number between 0 and 1")
#>     if (!is.null(y)) {
#>         dname <- paste(deparse(substitute(x)), "and", deparse(substitute(y)))
#>         if (paired) 
#>             xok <- yok <- complete.cases(x, y)
#>         else {
#>             yok <- !is.na(y)
#>             xok <- !is.na(x)
#>         }
#>         y <- y[yok]
#>     }
#>     else {
#>         dname <- deparse(substitute(x))
#>         if (paired) 
#>             stop("'y' is missing for paired test")
#>         xok <- !is.na(x)
#>         yok <- NULL
#>     }
#>     x <- x[xok]
#>     if (paired) {
#>         x <- x - y
#>         y <- NULL
#>     }
#>     nx <- length(x)
#>     mx <- mean(x)
#>     vx <- var(x)
#>     if (is.null(y)) {
#>         if (nx < 2) 
#>             stop("not enough 'x' observations")
#>         df <- nx - 1
#>         stderr <- sqrt(vx/nx)
#>         if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * abs(mx)) 
#>             stop("data are essentially constant")
#>         tstat <- (mx - mu)/stderr
#>         method <- if (paired) 
#>             "Paired t-test"
#>         else "One Sample t-test"
#>         estimate <- setNames(mx, if (paired) 
#>             "mean of the differences"
#>         else "mean of x")
#>     }
#>     else {
#>         ny <- length(y)
#>         if (nx < 1 || (!var.equal && nx < 2)) 
#>             stop("not enough 'x' observations")
#>         if (ny < 1 || (!var.equal && ny < 2)) 
#>             stop("not enough 'y' observations")
#>         if (var.equal && nx + ny < 3) 
#>             stop("not enough observations")
#>         my <- mean(y)
#>         vy <- var(y)
#>         method <- paste(if (!var.equal) 
#>             "Welch", "Two Sample t-test")
#>         estimate <- c(mx, my)
#>         names(estimate) <- c("mean of x", "mean of y")
#>         if (var.equal) {
#>             df <- nx + ny - 2
#>             v <- 0
#>             if (nx > 1) 
#>                 v <- v + (nx - 1) * vx
#>             if (ny > 1) 
#>                 v <- v + (ny - 1) * vy
#>             v <- v/df
#>             stderr <- sqrt(v * (1/nx + 1/ny))
#>         }
#>         else {
#>             stderrx <- sqrt(vx/nx)
#>             stderry <- sqrt(vy/ny)
#>             stderr <- sqrt(stderrx^2 + stderry^2)
#>             df <- stderr^4/(stderrx^4/(nx - 1) + stderry^4/(ny - 
#>                 1))
#>         }
#>         if (stderr < 10 * .Machine$double.eps * max(abs(mx), 
#>             abs(my))) 
#>             stop("data are essentially constant")
#>         tstat <- (mx - my - mu)/stderr
#>     }
#>     if (alternative == "less") {
#>         pval <- pt(tstat, df)
#>         cint <- c(-Inf, tstat + qt(conf.level, df))
#>     }
#>     else if (alternative == "greater") {
#>         pval <- pt(tstat, df, lower.tail = FALSE)
#>         cint <- c(tstat - qt(conf.level, df), Inf)
#>     }
#>     else {
#>         pval <- 2 * pt(-abs(tstat), df)
#>         alpha <- 1 - conf.level
#>         cint <- qt(1 - alpha/2, df)
#>         cint <- tstat + c(-cint, cint)
#>     }
#>     cint <- mu + cint * stderr
#>     names(tstat) <- "t"
#>     names(df) <- "df"
#>     names(mu) <- if (paired || !is.null(y)) 
#>         "difference in means"
#>     else "mean"
#>     attr(cint, "conf.level") <- conf.level
#>     rval <- list(statistic = tstat, parameter = df, p.value = pval, 
#>         conf.int = cint, estimate = estimate, null.value = mu, 
#>         stderr = stderr, alternative = alternative, method = method, 
#>         data.name = dname)
#>     class(rval) <- "htest"
#>     rval
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000017f32b58>
#> <environment: namespace:stats>

## pull up t.test.formula source code
getAnywhere(t.test.formula)
#> A single object matching 't.test.formula' was found
#> It was found in the following places
#>   registered S3 method for t.test from namespace stats
#>   namespace:stats
#> with value
#> 
#> function (formula, data, subset, na.action, ...) 
#> {
#>     if (missing(formula) || (length(formula) != 3L) || (length(attr(terms(formula[-2L]), 
#>         "term.labels")) != 1L)) 
#>         stop("'formula' missing or incorrect")
#>     m <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
#>     if (is.matrix(eval(m$data, parent.frame()))) 
#>         m$data <- as.data.frame(data)
#>     m[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
#>     m$... <- NULL
#>     mf <- eval(m, parent.frame())
#>     DNAME <- paste(names(mf), collapse = " by ")
#>     names(mf) <- NULL
#>     response <- attr(attr(mf, "terms"), "response")
#>     g <- factor(mf[[-response]])
#>     if (nlevels(g) != 2L) 
#>         stop("grouping factor must have exactly 2 levels")
#>     DATA <- setNames(split(mf[[response]], g), c("x", "y"))
#>     y <- do.call("t.test", c(DATA, list(...)))
#>     y$data.name <- DNAME
#>     if (length(y$estimate) == 2L) 
#>         names(y$estimate) <- paste("mean in group", levels(g))
#>     y
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x000000001807a9a0>
#> <environment: namespace:stats>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleverness is mathematical, not related to the software implementation.

Remember, all a paired t-test does to get the mean differences is to sum the differences between column one and column 2 (think `sum(post[1] - pre[1], post[2] - pre[2], post[3] - pre[3] ...` etc), and divide by the length of the data frame (`nrow(d)`). The sum of differences can be rearranged to `sum(post[1:10] - pre[1:10])`, which itself can be rearranged to `sum(post) - sum(pre)`. So the sum of the differences is equal to the differences of the sums. Of course, `nrow(d)` stays the same, so the mean of differences will always be the same, regardless of order.

You'll notice that the p value and t scores are slightly different when you change the order. That's because the *distribution* of differences will be different when you shuffle the observations. However, the *sum* of differences (and hence their mean) remains the same.

Comment: I never really thought about that the sum of the difference is the same as the differences of the sums. That's great! Looking further I found this answer illustrating this nicely: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148876/32477 This makes clear why the mean of the differences is always the same in all examples. But it still doesn't answer my question as to how (or where in) the `t.test()` function, with `paired = T`, the matching of `PRE` and `POST` occurs (when data is in the long format), since the correct matching is needed to get the correct standard errors (and hence t and p-values), no?

Comment: @Stefan It _doesn't_ match them up. It assumes they are matched by order. The relevant part of the function is `if(paired) x <- x - y`. Look closely at your SEs, t, and p values, and run the shuffling of the data frame again before you repeat the test. The SEs, p and t values will be different. They're _not_ correct after you change the order (unless by chance). In your example they are quite close because you have chosen random variables so you would expect them to be so. If you try this on real data, the results may be very different, but in either case they are plain wrong.

Comment: Yes matched by order makes sense in the simplest case, i.e. when you add the values as two separate vectors such `t.test(x, y, paired = T)`. Then I can quickly recalculate by hand in R. But I am having difficulties understanding when the data is in the long format (in a data frame) and passed as model representation into `t.test(y ~ x, paired = T, data = somedata)`. Will the function revert (the model specification) back internally into two separate vectors and then do the calculation on them (`x <- x - y`), ...

Comment: or is it doing something like `d_long[d_long$treat == "PRE",]$values - d_long[d_long$treat == "POST",]$values`? This would give the same results for `d_long` and `d_long_arranged`. See that there is also a _t.test formula_ source code (the second one). My apologies if my question is badly phrased, and thanks for helping me out here!